# Microsoft Edge fails to play PlayReady DASH stream in VideoJS

Tags: ffmpeg, microsoft-edge, video.js, mpeg-dash, playready

I have encoded some videos to x264 with ffmpeg, and packaged it to mpeg-dash with Widevine + PlayReady DRM using Shaka Packager.
With VideoJS the Widevine stream plays perfectly on both Chrome and MS Edge.
However, when I try to play the PlayReady stream on Edge, it just plays the first few seconds and then the image freezes. The audio does continue.
I see this error in the console:
[VIDEOJS: ERROR: DOMException: Failed to execute 'changeType' on 'SourceBuffer': Changing to the type provided ('video/mp4;codecs="avc1.4d401f"') is not supported.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKB3S.png)

What I don't understand is why it says the codec is unsupported, when it plays the exact same video fine, using Widevine. The PlayReady license server also doesn't give an error at all, it's all 200 OK.

The PlayReady stream works fine on other PlayReady supporting devices like a Roku or a Chromecast.

Does anyone have any idea about what the problem could be here?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It seems to be a VideoJS error, since the exact same PlayReady stream plays fine in a DRM test player (https://bitmovin.com/demos/drm). That still doesn't solve my issue though...

Comment: How about PlayReady on Chrome and other Edge channels like Edge Dev?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, Chrome does not support PlayReady at all. Edge Dev shows the exact same error, so that doesn't really help...

Comment: Hi,
I wanted to share that we are having the same issue with videos that are hosted on Brightcove.  They are sporadic and not happening with all videos and/or all viewers.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziR5M.png

Brightcove have been little to no help at all, which is disappointing considering the premium you pay for their service.  It is a really strange issue in that it works on some devices, operating systems and browsers and not others.  This is making it very difficult to isolate the root cause.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for sharing! This is indeed a very irritating problem. The way I fixed it, was by also loading the now obsolete "videojs contrib dash". Even when not directly using it, it did solve my problem weirdly enough. Could you tell me a little bit more about the type of video you are trying to load? Is it a static mp4, hls, dash, etc? Maybe we could figure out a cause...

Comment: And I would also be interested to hear which devices and browsers cause these errors for you! Since, for me, they are only caused with certain streams in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10...